# a href onclick event is not working if there a rel attribute defined on it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a onclick event for a href , but if a define a rel the function is not getting called

```
<a href="http://somewebsite" 
   onclick="javascript:someFunction('somevalue');" 
   name="top" 
   rel="somevalue">testing </a>
```

If I remove the `rel` property the onclick is working just fine.

What's up with that?

Comment: what happens if you keep it in one line?

Comment: I **cannot** reproduce the error: http://jsfiddle.net/94pCe/. Probably it is something else...

Comment: @breezer it was on one line--I edited it for our benefit

Comment: I could not reproduce this behavior. Also you do not need the `javascript:` protocol on `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Which browser? I just tried it on FF4, IE8, and Chrome with an alert() and it worked just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKovacs/C5KJV/

Comment: @Felix Kling I couldnt either >.<

Comment: @all for some reason in my code, when i remove the rel its work , if i keep the rel it doesn't fire. let me debug agian.

Comment: @felix , change the alert statement to a function call and check.

Comment: @all if you change it to function its not working...

Comment: are you getting any JavaScript errors when you click?

Comment: @matt i am not getting any errors

Comment: @all , looks like someother problem , i will debug more and get back to you guys soon.

Comment: @gov: Still works with a user defined function: http://jsfiddle.net/94pCe/1/

Comment: @felix , can you please go to http://www.art.com/photostoart/ and try to click overview , framing , canvas etc, they are having click events which are not getting fired.It should call trackforGA method.

Comment: @felix , if i remove rel attribute there it starts working...its a landing page done by someone else.

Comment: seeing the page/source, now I'm really curious.  $('#countrytabs li:first').click(trackForGA); works when I click 'overview', so something strange is going on.  I don't notice any bad quote marks or anything.

Comment: @matt they don't know much jquery , thats why they did like this...

Comment: @gov wasn't suggesting you should be using jQuery, but rather that a click event was indeed firing, and your function being called was in fact properly loaded

Comment: @matt , thanks for your time,  if i click that overflow , that method is not getting called , put a break point it won't hit. If i remove rel=""; it starts working , i know rel might not be problem...but something else is happening.

Comment: What ended up being the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is really an answer, but really more of a debugging diagnostic.  Plus, it was getting a bit long for use in the comments section.

1. There are no JS errors for me in either Chrome 7 or FF 3.6.8
2. There are no apparent unclosed quotes in the anchor tag
3. While the rel tag is not directly supported by any modern browser (but rather used by search spiders), the consensus is that it shouldn't affect events.  In fact, per some user comments, such @James Kovaks, it works fine in [his tests](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKovacs/C5KJV/).
4. From the Chrome JS console, the function trackForGA is visible, and executable without error.
5. Attaching an event with jQuery, and then clicking, fires the event as expected.  This tells us the click event is in fact being fired by the browser.

code:

```
  $('#countrytabs li:first').click(trackForGA); // click overview tab
```

Suggested next steps:

- Try other event types, to see if they are affected as well - such as onmouseover.
- Begin removing JavaScript that is not related to this particular event.  Specifically, the only JS you want to remain is the trackForGa function and the onclick JS.  Even remove externally loaded JS, such as jQuery (you can presumably do this on a local test/dev box)
- If the problem persists, remove trackForGa and instead just do an alert() from the onclick event.
- If the problem persists, run your site through an HTML validator (http://validator.w3.org/)
- If the problem persists after fixing validation problems, begin removing unrelated HTML tags and content.  Systematically remove items until the click is firing as expected to identify a potential culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you never need to specify "`javascript:`" in an onclick. The only thing that can follow *is* JavaScript.

Comment: In this context, that expression is a label: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label which is useless in the context. (This answer, however, should be a comment).

Comment: @david , even in the jsfiddle, when i change the alert to a function call its failing

Comment: @gov — that statement doesn't appear to have anything to do with what it appears to be a response to.

Comment: `javascript:` defines a label, which you use at the start of a loop so you can jump to it from inside the loop. They are useful when you have nested loops. They aren't useful when you have no loop at all.

Comment: @david , if i give you the production url can you take a look at it.